# MVC4 Code First Database type "Date"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need a database column to be a `date` data type in a MS SQL Server.  It's a requirement for the project, it cannot be `datetime.`

In my model I have:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? RequestedCompletionDate { get; set; }
```

This still creates the column as a nullable datetime.  Is there any way to make it `date` code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I finally figured out how to do it.

In my model rather than using the `DataType` attribute I used the `column` attribute.  My model now looks like this:

```
[Column(TypeName="date")]
public DateTime? RequestedCompletionDate { get; set; }
```

If anyone is trying to do something similar, although I used `TypeName="date"`, you should be able to set `TypeName` to anything you want as long as it is a valid SQL Server Data Type.